# Template code not detected in program using Django

Tags: python, django

I want to make a slider in my home page, but when I try it, I cannot make it work.

**model.py**:

```py
class Static(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description     = models.TextField()
    images1         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")
    images2         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title;
```

**view.py**:

```py
def slider(request):
    slider = Static.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'kerajinan/home.html', {
        'slider' : slider,
    })
```

**admin.py**:

```py
admin.site.register(Static)
```

template **home.html**:

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for i in slider %}
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="{{i.image1.url}}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                <img src="{{i.image2.url}}"  class="pricing" alt="" />
            </div>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Below the code `<div class="carousel-inner">`, it's not read in this program.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your Static model is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define an action that will get the image url, but try changing your html template first. The values you have do not match your model. You have `image1` instead of `images1` It should be:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="{{i.images1.url}}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
    <img src="{{i.images2.url}}" class="pricing" alt="" />
</div>
```

**- - - EDIT:**

You need to define a function that will return the image url when called in the html file. As of now, `{{ i.images1.url }}` doesn't return the proper value since url isn't defined.

Try this:

*models:*

```
class Static(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    images1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")
    images2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title;

    def get_images1_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.images1)

    def get_images2_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.images2)
```

*html:*

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for i in slider %}
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="{{ i.get_images1_url }}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                <img src="{{ i.get_images2_url }}"  class="pricing" alt="" />
            </div>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

*settings:*

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), #"First directory", "Second directory", etc, if applicable)
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, I can help you set up an action to get the image url.

Comment: how to set up an action?